# Networking; Router 10/100 to gigabit switch then PC.. Gigabit network xfer speeds?

Tags: networking, router, file-transfer

This is just for a home setup, my router is a DSL box and I've not found a decent ADSL2+ modem that's also a gigabit +wifi router.. So this is my next-best idea..

DSL Router is 10/100 to a Gigabit switch.. The PCs are hooked up to the gigabit switch, along with a NAS- Will the PCs and NAS exchange data at gigabit speeds, being connected to the switch, or will the router's fast ethernet limit the switch's throughput?

The PCs in question all run Windows 10 and are modern machines equipped with gigabit NICs, so the only possible limiting factor would be the router behind the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your internal nodes are gigabit your internal speeds will be as fast as the hardware will run if all connected to a gigabit switch. Your slowdown will be transfers through your DSL Router that said unless you have a really fast internet connection in excess of 70mps you will not be bottlenecked by the transfer rate for streaming or www browsing.
It’s a misconception that just because your connected with a gigabit NIC that you will be able to transfer at that speed. Most home systems will not get anywhere near that transfer speed.

Comment: I had a decent gigabit+wifi router setup before moving to the Philippines, but left it behind. The service here is laughable but I still need gigabit xfer speeds for the NAS and PCs over the internal network, I'm aware anything outside my home will go through the DSL and be capped there. I just needed to know if stuff inside (eg connected to the switch) will give me 1000mbps speeds. (My home setup before was reliably pushing 110+mB/s to the NAS and back)

Answer (score 0):

Purchased a cheapo gigabit switch based on the above answer and am confirming it works as indicated.

[image: Network Layout with GBe Switch and 10/100 Router]

PCs and NAS connected directly to the switch see sustained transfers between them of 95-112mB/sec.  Thank you for your replies. :)